# Family Control API for Parent Device doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift

guys! I have been developing the app that is required to use FamilyControll API and other related frameworks. I have successfully made child device authorised with Family API, but on parent device it shows an error:

`Error Domain=FamilyControls.FamilyControlsError Code=2 "(null)"`

I found that link (https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682257) and it's written here, that *FamilyControlsError Code=2 is the error code for an invalid account type; this is expected when trying to authorize FamilyControls on a non-child iCloud account.*

My question is - how can I authorise my parent using Family Control API in order to use for example `DeviceActivity` framework and `ManegedSettings` framework?

Comment: You can’t it is only available for child accounts per the documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/familycontrols/authorizationcenter/requestauthorization(completionhandler:)

Comment: But how can I get activity data from child's device? and moreover put some restrictions?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10123

Comment: yeah, I saw this video few times. I just can't understand how parent device works if it couldn't authorise?

Comment: I'm testing my app on two real devices, on iPad I have signed in as child, on iPhone as parent, but when I launch app on parent device in console I have message I wrote in topic

Comment: You don't launch the child app on your parent device. You launch the parent app. The parent app uses the [DeviceActivity framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/deviceactivity/) to monitor activity and set restrictions.

Comment: You can request authorisation with AuthorizationCenter.shared.requestAuthorization(for: FamilyControlsMember.individual)